# NAudio trying to load MP3 stream into Mp3FileReader wont read

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, naudio

I am using NAudio to combine mp3 files into one to produce a sound.
It then saves it into a stream. then I take that stream and I try to instantiate a new Mp3FileReader object because I need to read the mp3 length in milliseconds but I get:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invalid MP3 file - no MP3 Frames Detected
```

the code that generates the mp3 into the stream:

```
 public void MorseBuilder(string msg,out byte[] audio, out TimeSpan time)
    {
        MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream();
        var decoded = Decode(msg);

        foreach (var letter in decoded)
        {
            switch (letter)
            {
                case '.':

                    Combine("dot.mp3", st);
                    break;

                case '-':

                    Combine("dash.mp3", st);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(st); //Exception
        audio = st.ToArray();
        time = reader.TotalTime;

       // return st.ToArray();
    }

    public void Combine(string file, Stream output)
    {

        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file);
        
        if ((output.Position == 0) && (reader.Id3v2Tag != null))
        {
            output.Write(reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData, 0, reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData.Length);
        }
        Mp3Frame frame;
        while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
        {
            output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this what you need? https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/272

Comment: not realy. it seems that he just told him to remove the line that loads the MP3 from the stream lol.. I believe he was just using NAudio in a wrong way.

Comment: my problem is simply when I try to load an MP3 file from the Stream it wont read it.

Comment: but when I save the file first, the load it into a new stream and then load it it works.